# problem with Adminer & PHP 8.0 on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, adminer

So i updated my version of php to the new version (8.0). And everything works fine, except for my adminer.

It's caused by my version of adminer being out of date because php8.0 doesn't have the function magic_quotes.

And the only command i have find to get adminer is this one:
sudo apt-get install adminer

But it doesn't work...

Comment: The problem isn't that it needs to be enabled. The problem is the function got *removed entirely* in PHP 8. You need a more recent Adminer version. https://www.php.net/get_magic_quotes_gpc

Comment: Well on php.net they seed the function was already outdate for php 7.4 but i was using php 7.4 with adminer and it was working fine... Weird.
I'll try to get a more recent version of adminer then.

Comment: Yes, it was *deprecated* but still there in PHP 7.4. It was removed completely in 8.0.

Comment: @ceejayoz Do you know where i can find the console command to install the latest version of adminer ? Everywhere i go they use "apt install adminer" but it's the exact same version than im using... :/

Comment: Actually, it looks like Adminer doesn't currently work with PHP8. There's a pull request at https://github.com/vrana/adminer/pull/401 to fix this issue and some others.

Comment: Is there any error message you can share? Also, how is this related to programming?

Answer (score 4):

Support was added in December 2020, unfortunately only weeks after your question @The-Evil-Fox. The only problem is it seems the Ubuntu repo is not up to date so if you install via apt install adminer you'll still be on a version that doesn't support PHP 8.

The easiest way I found to update is to still install it that way, but then use wget to download the latest version of adminer.php. So do something like this:

- Go to the adminer director `cd /usr/share/adminer`
- Download the latest version of adminer: `sudo wget https://www.adminer.org/latest.php`
- Delete adminer.php
- Then rename latest.php to adminer.php -> `sudo mv latest.php adminer.php`

Done! That worked for me anyway... I'm not a Ubuntu pro though, so no idea why repo is so out of date.